# gnome-disks not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, mount, udisks

**Unable to launch gnome-disks**

```
GNOME-Disks-ERROR **: 08:30:40.733: Error getting udisks client: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.UDisks2: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
[1]    91470 trace trap (core dumped)  /usr/bin/gnome-disks
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Check udisks2 logs

```
journalctl -u udisks2.service
```

In my case there was a bunch of errors related to missing symbols:

```
failed to load bd_crypto_luks_get_metadata_size: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbd_crypto.so.2: undefined symbol: bd_crypto_luks_get_metadata_size
failed to load bd_crypto_luks_format_luks2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbd_crypto.so.2: undefined symbol: bd_crypto_luks_format_luks2
```

If you have the same, try to install/upgrade the libblockdev-crypto2 package:

```
sudo apt-get install libblockdev-crypto2=2.23-2ubuntu3
```

2.23-2ubuntu3 version of the package has missing symbols.
Hope this helps.
Cheers